How to tweak my glmmTMB model to address several items? i.e. covariates, reference levels, random factors, and zero-inflation model
I recently ran a Zero-inflated negative binomial mixed model (ZINB hereafter) using the glmmTMB function from the glmmTMB package.
I ran a dietary experiment where I gave adult snails a phosphorus-enriched diet and a phosphorous-depleted diets (P). Total number of snails is 99 and we gave half the low P diet and the other half high P diet.
The snails can have 3 ploidy levels (diploid, triploid, tetraploid). Nested within ploidy level are 10 lineages. The diploid snails are sexual and the triploid and tetraploid snails are asexual. Only the diploids need to mate to make embryos. Lineage is a random factor and will always be nested underneath a ploidy level. For example, Lineage A can only be diploid. It can never be triploid nor tetraploid.
My dependent variable is embryo count, which is zero-inflated and the highest embryo number is 49.
We measured adult length (Length). I would like to keep Length in the model a covariate since there is a significant linear relationship with embryo number.
This is my code:
TMBNBNEST <- glmmTMB(Embryonumber ~ P*Ploidy + Length + 
               (1|Ploidy:Lineage), ziformula = ~ Presence,  
               data = x, family = "nbinom2")
summary(TMBNBNEST)


Embryonumber is my dependent variable.
Presence is binary dependent variable of reproduction. 0 is non-reproductive snail, 1 is
reproductive snail.
(1 | represents the random intercept
Ploidy:Lineage is Lineage nested in Ploidy.
P*Ploidy is short-hand way to represent stand alone variables, and interaction P treatment and Ploidy.
Length is a covariate.
x is my data.

I received this output:
Family: nbinom2  ( log )
Formula:          Embryonumber ~ P * Ploidy + Length + (1 | Lineage)
Zero inflation:                ~ Presence
Data: x

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   538.3    566.8   -258.2    516.3       88 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups  Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 Lineage (Intercept) 3.601e-10 1.898e-05
Number of obs: 99, groups:  Lineage, 10

Dispersion parameter for nbinom2 family (): 2.41 

Conditional model:
                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)             0.9109     0.9283   0.981   0.3265  
PLow                   -0.3258     0.2951  -1.104   0.2696  
PloidyTetraploid       -0.6318     0.2723  -2.320   0.0203 *
PloidyTriploid         -0.1240     0.2743  -0.452   0.6513  
Length                  0.4479     0.2141   2.092   0.0364 *
PLow:PloidyTetraploid  -0.0741     0.4079  -0.182   0.8559  
PLow:PloidyTriploid     0.2356     0.4020   0.586   0.5577  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Zero-inflation model:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)    22.52   17159.83   0.001    0.999
Presence      -45.11   19430.50  -0.002    0.998

Question 1: I have been reading "glmmTMB Balances Speed and Flexibility Among Packages for Zero-inflated Generalized Linear Mixed Modeling". I have not seen any mention of how to code covariates. I did see 2 posts (post 1 and post 2) that code them the same way I have. Have I coded my length as a covariate correctly?

I have discussed this with my advisor but I believe I have coded the covariate correctly because R automatically knew "Length" is a numeric class.

Question 2: I have 2 variations of P treatment: low vs high. I have 3 ploidy levels: di, tri, and tetra. The reference level for low P treatment (Plow in output). The reference level for PloidyTetraploid and PloidyTriploid is PloidyDiploid. What is the reference level for the interaction effects Plow: PloidyTetraploid and Plow: PloidyTriploid? I believe the reference level is Phigh:PloidyDiploid because:

PHigh is the reference level for Plow.
The reference level for PloidyTetraploid and PloidyTriploid is PloidyDiploid.
If the reference level for the interaction effect was Plow:PloidyDiploid then we would be testing a Ploidy effect only since all combinations would comparing Plow.

However, If Phigh:PloidyDiploid is my interaction reference level like I assume - how can we compare Plow:PloidyDiploid?

We already compared Plow:PloidyDiploid to Phigh:PloidyDiploid as a standalone factor as PHigh vs Plow

Question 3: It seems that the p value of the random factors are not commonly reported: https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#testing-significance-of-random-effects
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68120632/how-do-i-find-the-p-value-for-my-random-effect-in-my-linear-mixed-effect-model
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2008q2/000904.html
However, is there some other statistic that I can report for my random factor (lineage)? Should I report the variance and standard deviation? Maybe I can run a maximum likelihood ratio to obtain a p value?

I am checking how others in my field report the significance values for  random factors!

Question 4: This is most likely the most important question so again I was reading "glmmTMB Balances Speed and Flexibility Among Packages for Zero-inflated Generalized Linear Mixed Modeling". And found this excerpt:
"To fit zero-inflated models, we use the ziformula argument, or glmmTMB will also recognize zi. This is a formula that describes how the probability of an extra zero (i.e., structural zero) will vary with predictors. In this example, we might assume that absences will at least vary by species (spp), so we write zi= ~ spp. This formula only has a right side because the left side is always the probability of having a structural zero in the response that was specified in the first formula. The zero-inflation probability is always modeled with a logit link to keep it between 0 and 1."
Presence in my model is a binary dependent variable. I would like to test if there is an influence of Lineage, P, Ploidy, or Length on Presence. I thought that the response variable (Presence) used in the ziformula goes on the right outside of the "~". But now I think that my model should be:
TMBNBNEST <- glmmTMB(Embryonumber ~ P*Ploidy + Length + 
               (1|Ploidy:Lineage),    
               ziformula = ~ P*Ploidy + Length + (1|Ploidy:Lineage), 
               data = x, family = "nbinom2")
summary(TMBNBNEST)

Does this mean that the right side of my equation should not be a binary response but instead a repeat of my factors (from the conditional model)?

I have looked at other posts and re read the the linked PDF - the right side of my formula should include my conditional model or ~. (factors in my conditional model). The rights side of the formula should not be the  my dependent variable recoded as binary.


A few notes - your basic model, including the length covariate, looks good.  Given the biology you should probably leave lineage as a random effect regardless of its "significance"   this can be assessed if needed with AIC or IIRC a p value, but you need to set up a reduced modelw without the random effect, which can get trickerier for some functions; I forget If glmmTMB let's your run models without a random effect.  Your zi function looks overly complex esp given sample size but I have use zi for a while

Also zi is always a one sided formula IIRC.  Often with just one covariate eg length but again its bee a while

Your first question comes up so often I'm surprised I can't find some kind of canonical answer; you're correct that Phigh and PloidyDiploid are reference levels so Plow is the Plow:PloidyDiploid effect (the other predictor remains at its reference). For Q4 it seems like Presence is a perfect predictor of embryo > 0 -- not unreasonable if you recorded both accurately -- but the question whether mating occured or whether there's >0 embryos are two different ones, so you might consider a logistic regression with Presence as outcome there.

Question 1 is still iffy. It seems that covariates share the same syntax as fixed factors in glmmTMB, but we are unsure. Do either of you have any works (other than stack exchange network) that talk about covariates in glmmTMB? I may post this question on stack overflow.
Question 2: @PBulls, can you expand on the reference levels a bit more? It seems that we both agree on the reference levels for standalone P treatment and standalone Ploidy. I am confused about your response to the reference levels for an interaction of P treatment and Ploidy.

Question 3: There are ways to report the significance of random factors – thank you @ N Brouwer! I am going to check what the literature similar to my work reports random factors after using glmmTMB.

Question 4: I have received 2 responses but not a straight answer. The diploid snails are sexual and the triploid and tetraploid snails are asexual. Only the diploids need to mate to make embryos. This is important information that I will now add to my post. Based on Zuur, Alain, et al. Mixed Effects Models and Extensions in Ecology with R, Springer New York, 2009 it seems that these non-true zeros are considered in ZINBs. However, we cannot be sure now that all the diploid females mated with the diploid males – we did not video-record their interactions.

Sorry, I meant Q2 instead of Q1; the specification for the former looks fine assuming you wanted a slope/continuous predictor. Interactions only actually add parameters that are not already in the model. Maybe a tutorial like this can be helpful (not mine).
